# NoClassDefFoundError in threads

Tags: java, multithreading, classpath

Hi I got a exception NoClassDefFoundError when I run a thread.
This process runs well when i execute without threads, but when I execute the start method, I got this error in different statements

Is it possible that threads got a different class path that the main thread?

thanks
edit to add code

Run method:

```
public void run(){
    try{
        boolean startAction = HeapThread.addAction(idCliente, idThread, Constants.ACTION_CREATE_TOPIC);
        if (!startAction) {
            synchronized (this){
                this.wait();
            }
        }
        createTopic();
    }
    catch(Exception ex){
        log.error("Error", ex);
    }
    finally {
        Long nextIdThread = HeapThread.getNextAction(idCliente, idThread, Constants.ACTION_CREATE_TOPIC);
        if (nextIdThread > 0){
            log.debug("Thread");
            ThreadState thread = HeapThread.getState(nextIdThread);
            synchronized (thread) {
                thread.notify();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

createTopic() function calls searchBlog() and there I call this

```
try{
        sessionId = SessionWS.createSession(url, false);
        CrawlerSearch crawler = new CrawlerSearchAPIService(new URL(url + Constants.URL_CRAWLER), new QName(Constants.QNAME_CRAWLER, "CrawlerSearchAPIService")).getCrawlerSearchAPIPort();
        // para cada topico obtnemos 10 blogs
        for (Long idTopic : blogsTopics.keySet()) {
```

...

and full exception is:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/befasoft/common/business/webservices/client/Session
at com.befasoft.common.business.webservices.client.SessionAPIService.getSessionAPIPort(SessionAPIService.java:56)
at com.befasoft.common.business.webservices.SessionWS.createSession(SessionWS.java:21)
at com.humanlike.web.tools.Crawler.searchBlogs(Crawler.java:50)
at com.humanlike.web.theads.CreateTopic.createTopic(CreateTopic.java:164)
at com.humanlike.web.theads.CreateTopic.run(CreateTopic.java:63)
```

Comment: Without a special intervention, the new thread will inherit the classloader from the originating thread. You won't get much help if you don't post your code.

Comment: @Kongol :can you be please more specific.Please post the complete code if possible.

Comment: Each therad has its own `ClassLoader`, which extends the parent classLoader, you need to set the class loader to the thread.
Ideally you should not be getting this exception, can you explain what is your setup (tomcat, weblogic etc)

Comment: ... and the exact stacktrace of the error, with an indication of lines of code the stacktrace pertains to.

Comment: @AnanthaSharma Each thread has its **context classloader**, but that's a different mechanism. It causes `ClassNotFoundException`s and not `NoClassDefFoundError`s.

Comment: added code and @AnanthaSharma I use tomcat 7 and structs 2.0

Answer (score 1):

My guess is that `com.befasoft.common.business.webservices.client.Session` had previously failed with `ExceptionInInitializerError`. This gives `NoClassDefFoundError` for subsequent calls. Check the log from beginning.

Answer (score 1):

Solver, I just have to especify the thread class loader with that

```
ct.setContextClassLoader(ClassLoader.getSystemClassLoader());
```

Thx Anantha Sharma for guide me